# Remove NULL element and unlist the local level list from a nested list in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list, say it has three levels:

```
tmp =list(list(list(c(2,9,10), NULL), c(1,3,4,6)), 7)
```

This would output

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]] 
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1]  2  9 10

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 3 4 6

[[2]]
[1] 7
```

I would like to remove the NULL element and the local level of the list. i.e, the nested list tmp has only 2 levels and it becomes

```
tmp =list(list(c(2,9,10), c(1,3,4,6)), 7).
```

That is, the desired output would either be the following:

```
tmp
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1]  2  9 10

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 3 4 6

[[2]]
[1] 7
```

I have tried to search for the index position of NULL but without luck. Furthermore, I am not sure how to detect and unlist the list that contains the NULL element within the list.
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically, you remove `NULL` elements on a flat list with

```
ll <- list( 1, 2, NULL, 3 )
ll <- ll[ ! sapply(ll, is.null) ]
```

If you do not know the structure in advance, this is a clear case to combine this solution with a recursive function:

```
removeNullRec <- function( x ){  
  x <- x[ !sapply( x, is.null ) ]
  if( is.list(x) ){
    x <- lapply( x, removeNullRec)
  }
  return(x)
}

removeNullRec(tmp)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1]  2  9 10


[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 3 4 6


[[2]]
[1] 7
```

**Edit**

It's always good to rephrase the problem as simple as possible. What I understood from your comments is, that (independent of the occurrence of `NULL` elements) you want to *replace each element which contains only one child by the child itself*. There is also another case which has to be considered then: Two sibling leafs could be `NULL` as well. So lets start with a little bit more complicated example:

[image]

```
tree <- list(
  list(
    list(
      list(
        list( NULL, NULL ),
        list( NULL, NULL )
      ),
      7
    ),
    list(
      list(
        list( c(1,2), NULL ),
        c(3,4)
))))
```

This isolated problem to flat the tree is of course also solved best by applying recursive approach:

```
flatTreeRec <- function( x ){
  if( is.list(x) ){
    # recursion
    x <- lapply( x, flatTree )
    # remove empty branches
    x <- x[ sapply( x, length ) > 0 ]
    # flat branches with only child
    if( length(x) == 1 ){
      x <- x[[1]]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

flatTreeRec( removeNullRec(tree) )
```

And of course you can directly combine this two functions to avoid stressing your stack twice:

```
removeNullAndFlatTreeRec <- function( x ){  
  x <- x[ !sapply( x, is.null ) ]
  if( is.list(x) ){
    x <- lapply( x, removeNullRec)
    x <- x[ sapply( x, length ) > 0 ]
    if( length(x) == 1 ){
      x <- x[[1]]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

removeNullAndFlatTreeRec( tree )
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I was wondering if the list that contains the NULL element could be unlisted from the nested list. For my above example, if an NULL element is detected in the list, then I unlist the list, so that the nested list has only 2 lists. i.e., list(list(c(2,9,10), c(1,3,4,6)), 7). Your function preserves the same number of lists as in the original list.

Comment: Thanks! Your code works at removing the NULL element. However it does not remove/unlist the list that contains the NULL element.

Comment: @user2498497 in which cases do you want to unlist the siblings of the `NULL` element? Only if it is the only sibling and is flat (i.e. does not contain any children)? And what about cases where a list element is the only element in the hierarchy and is flat. Do you want them to be unlisted although there is no `NULL` sibling? What should be the proper result of `list( list( list( 1,2,3 ), NULL ) )`?

Comment: The list structure I have is a nested list, each of which has length 2. (A binary tree essentially). If the node is a NULL, it will not have any children. Then this NULL element should be contained in a flat list with its siblings. Because of my (binary tree) list structure, it will not happen that a list element is the only element in the hierarchy and is flat. Also because of the list structure, list( list( list( 1,2,3 ), NULL ) ) will not happen. However, list(list(1, c(2,3)), NULL) may happen. In this case, the proper result will be list(1, c(2,3)). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this function:

```
removeNULL <- function(x){
    x <- Filter(Negate(is.null), x)
    if( is.list(x) ){
      x <- lapply( x, function(y) Filter(length, removeNULL(y)))
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Not only it remove the `NULL` elements, but it also removes the elements which are a list containing only `NULL` elements, such as `A2$A2$format$font` in the example below:

```
> A2
$A2
$A2$value
[1] 9.9

$A2$format
$A2$format$numberFormat
[1] "2Decimal"

$A2$format$font
$A2$format$font$name
NULL

$A2$format$font$bold
NULL

$A2$format$font$color
NULL



$A2$comment
NULL


> removeNULL(A2)
$A2
$A2$value
[1] 9.9

$A2$format
$A2$format$numberFormat
[1] "2Decimal"
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you @Stéphane, but I am trying to do something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58245155/10841085 and was wondering if you could please take a look? I have a tag list of Shiny inputs and would like to modify the label of each input while preserving the structure of the inputs list. I have defined a recursive function to do this but it changes the structure of the inputs list.

Answer (score 0):

**Update June 2020**: this can now also be done with `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (a revised version of base `rrapply`). Using `how = "prune"`, we can prune all `NULL` elements from the list while keeping the original list structure. For instance, using the same list objects as in Beasterfield's response:

```r
library(rrapply)

## Example 1 
tmp <- list(list(list(c(2,9,10), NULL), c(1,3,4,6)), 7) 

## keep only non-NULL leafs
rrapply(tmp, condition = Negate(is.null), how = "prune")
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1]  2  9 10
#> 
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 1 3 4 6
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 7


## Example 2
tree <- list(
    list(
        list(
            list(
                list( NULL, NULL ),
                list( NULL, NULL )
            ),
            7
        ),
        list(
            list(
                list( c(1,2), NULL ),
                c(3,4)
            ))))

## branches with only NULLs are completely pruned
rrapply(tree, condition = Negate(is.null), how = "prune")
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [[1]][[2]][[1]]
#> [[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]]
#> [[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]][[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 3 4
```