# Apply a recursive function to a nested list while preserving the classes of sublists

Tags: r, list, recursion, data-manipulation, htmltools

I have a nested list called `inputs`:

```
library(htmltools)
library(shiny)

inputs = tagList(
  selectInput('first', 'FIRST', letters), 
  checkboxInput('second', 'SECOND')
)

str(inputs, max.level = 1)
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
  ..- attr(*, "html_dependencies")=List of 1
 $ :List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.tag.list" "list"
```

I would like to modify all sublists who have class `shiny.tag` and whose `name` element equals `label` (see `inputs[[1]][["children"]][[1]]` for an example of such a sublist) but preserve the original structure of the list while doing so.

To do this, I define a recursive function `hideLabel`:

```
hideLabel <- function(tag.list) {

  lapply(tag.list, function(x) {

    if(inherits(x, 'shiny.tag')) {

      if(x$name == 'label') {

        tagAppendAttributes(x, style = 'display:none;')

      } else {

        hideLabel(x$children)

      }

    } else {

      return(x)

    }
  })
}
```

Here is the output of applying hideLabel to the inputs list:

```
res = hideLabel(inputs)

str(res, max.level = 1)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
 $ :List of 1
```

As shown above, hideLabel does not return a list of the same structure as the original list inputs (compare the output of str in the first code chunk with the output of str in the third chunk above). I was wondering if someone could help me understand why the function is doing this and how it could be modified? I have tried rewriting it several times to no avail.

**Update:**

I got it to work after thinking about what the function was returning at each stage. Here is the updated function:

```
hideLabel <- function(x) {

  children = x$children

  x$children = lapply(children, function(y) {

    if(inherits(y, 'shiny.tag')) {

      if(y$name == 'label') tagAppendAttributes(y, style = 'display:none;') else hil(y)

    } else y

  })

  return(x)

}
```

This preserves the structure of the original list:

```
inputs_new = lapply(inputs, hideLabel)

str(inputs, max.level = 1)
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
  ..- attr(*, "html_dependencies")=List of 1
 $ :List of 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.tag.list" "list"
```

NOTE: The class of the overall list changes though from `shiny.tag.list` to just `list`. Would anyone know how to prevent this from happening? I know I could use `do.call(tagList, inputs_new)` to manually add the `shiny.tag.list` class back on but that seems hacky.

Comment: You will need to share code of `tagAppendAttributes` to make this a reproducible example

Comment: It's a function from the `htmltools` package, I have included a `library` call in the header of my code so the result should be reproducible.

Comment: `I would like to modify all sublists who have class shiny.tag and whose name element equals label` modify to what? Also why do you think `tagAppendAttributes` would change the class of `x` in your function ?

Comment: No sorry, I would like to modify those sublists that have class `shiny.tag` and whose first element (`name`) equals `label` by applying the `tagAppendAttributes` function to them as so: `tagAppendAttributes(x, style = 'display:none;')`. `tagAppendAttributes` does not change the class of the tag. It's the `hideLabel` function that changes the class of tags that do not satisfy the `x$name == 'label'` condition during the recursion. Does this clarify it?

Comment: Basically, I need to go apply `tagAppendAttributes(x, style = 'display:none;')` to all label tags in the `inputs` list (label tags are all sublists with class `shiny.tag` AND name == 'label') while preserving the original structure of the `inputs` list (the structure is shown in the `str` output in the first chunk in my post).

Answer (score 0):

As of htmltools version 0.5.2 `tagAppendAttributes` gained the `.cssSelector` parameter, so we can simply do:

```
library(htmltools)

inputs = tagList(
  selectInput('first', 'FIRST', letters), 
  checkboxInput('second', 'SECOND')
)

inputs_new <- tagAppendAttributes(inputs, style = "display:none;", .cssSelector = "label")
```

PS: in this context also check `htmltools::tagQuery()`